# Pass dynamic value from jquery to MVC5 Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, grid, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've got a MVC5 page with 2 links / buttons and 1 Grid. Due to some dynamic display problems I cannot have more than 1 grid, so I'm changing the binding of the grid to show either Company Info or Company Income.

That works great.

Now I've got an export control that will call function ExportData in my Controller, but for the function to know which data set to export, I need to tell which data is currently bound. Because the jquery is client-side and razor is server-side, I'm having some difficulty in telling razor the current value.

So I've added a parameter called 'typeOfContent', but how can I populate the value of this?  In other words, in the code below, I want to add something where the ???? is (either CompanyInfo or CompanyIncome).

I don't think Razor will be able to read the value of the hidden HTML control?
Not sure how else I can tell ExportData which type of data is currently visible

```
@model int

<a href="#link1" data-loaded="true" id="btn-link1">Show Info</a>
<a href="#link2" data-loaded="false" id="btn-link2">Show Income</a>
....
 @Html.Hidden("TypeOfContent", "Temp");
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "MyController", 
                        new { CompanyID = Model, typeOfContent = ???? }, 
                        FormMethod.Post))
{
   <div id="MyGrid">
      @{Html.RenderAction("MyPartial", "MyController", new { CompanyID = Model});}
   </div>
}
....

<script>
 $(function () {
        bindCompanyInfo();

        $('#btn-link1').on('click', function (e) {
            bindCompanyInfo();
            $('#TypeOfContent').val("CompanyInfo");  
        })
        $('#btn-link2').on('click', function (e) {
            bindCompanyIncome();
            $('#TypeOfContent').val("CompanyIncome");  
        })    

    function bindCompanyInfo() {
       ...
        };
    }

    function bindCompanyIncome() {
      ...           
        };
    }
```

Comment: Cameron, Any reason why you couldn't add that hidden form value inside of your form which is being posted? If it posts from the form you shouldn't need to put the value inline in the .beginform method. You could do the same with CompanyID. I will post an example below.

Comment: No reason why not, besides the fact that I thought it will not work.  Seems to be working though.  Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can allow you to set and reset the value with javascript and post ok.

```
@model int

<a href="#link1" data-loaded="true" id="btn-link1">Show Info</a>
<a href="#link2" data-loaded="false" id="btn-link2">Show Income</a>
....

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("TypeOfContent");
    @Html.Hidden("CompanyID", Model);

    <div id="MyGrid">
        @{Html.RenderAction("MyPartial", "MyController", new { CompanyID = Model });}
    </div>
}
```